# Why am I getting an unexpected T_VARIABLE error in my Code Igniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this controller in Code Igniter that begins with

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller {
    private $data = array(
        'importantValueToPassToViews' => $this->Animal->getPrey(),
    );
    ...
```

I am getting an error on the line beginning with `'importantValueToPassToViews'` (the third line).

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

Why?

Comment: Are you sure Animal is a field and not a class?

Comment: Animal is an autoloaded model.

Comment: But it's not autoloaded until the controller is constructed.  You're getting an error for at least two different reasons here :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can't call a function in a class property definition.  You can set it to a constant, or an array of constants.

You'll need to do that in the constructor:

```
<?php
class MyController extends CI_Controller {

    private $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['importantValueToPassToViews'] = $this->Animal->getPrey();
    }
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. That resolves the original PHP error. However, when I pass `$data` into a view with `$this->load->view('viewPrey', $data);`, I cannot access the variable called `$importantValueToPassToViews` in the view. It apparently doesn't exist. Does this method change the $data variable outside the scope of the constructor function?

Comment: And how the heck do you know how to autoload, but don't know how to pass data to a view in CI? :P

Comment: lol that worked. thanks. good question. i skim documentation a lot :)